# Task Parallel Library WaitAny with specified result

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to write some code that will make a web service call to a number of different servers in parallel, so TPL seems like the obvious choice to use.

Only one of my web service calls will ever return the result I want and all the others won't. I'm trying to work out a way of effectively having a `Task.WaitAny` but only unblocking when the first `Task` that matches a condition returns.

I tried with `WaitAny` but couldn't work out where to put the filter. I got this far:

```
public void SearchServers()
{
    var servers = new[] {"server1", "server2", "server3", "server4"};
    var tasks = servers
                 .Select(s => Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(server => CallServer((string)server), s))
                 .ToArray();

    Task.WaitAny(tasks); //how do I say "WaitAny where the result is true"?

    //Omitted: cancel any outstanding tasks since the correct server has been found
}

private bool CallServer(string server)
{
    //... make the call to the server and return the result ...
}
```

**Edit**: Quick clarification just in case there's any confusion above. I'm trying to do the following:

1. For each server, start a `Task` to check it
2. Either, wait until a server returns true (only a max of 1 server will ever return true)
3. Or, wait until all servers have returned false, i.e. there was no match.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best of what I can think of is specifying a `ContinueWith` for each `Task`, checking the result, and if `true` cancelling the other tasks. For cancelling tasks you may want to use [CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.CancellationToken.aspx).

```
var tasks = servers
    .Select(s => Task.Run(...)
        .ContinueWith(t =>
            if (t.Result) {
                // cancel other threads
            }
        )
    ).ToArray();
```

UPDATE: An alternative solution would be to `WaitAny` until the right task completed (but it has some drawbacks, e.g. removing the finished tasks from the list and creating a new array out of the remaining ones is quite a heavy operation):

```
List<Task<bool>> tasks = servers.Select(s => Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(server => CallServer((string)server), s)).ToList();

bool result;
do {
    int idx = Task.WaitAny(tasks.ToArray());
    result = tasks[idx].Result;
    tasks.RemoveAt(idx);
} while (!result && tasks.Count > 0);

// cancel other tasks
```

UPDATE 2: Nowadays I would do it with Rx:

```
[Fact]
public async Task AwaitFirst()
{
    var servers = new[] { "server1", "server2", "server3", "server4" };
    var server = await servers
        .Select(s => Observable
            .FromAsync(ct => CallServer(s, ct))
            .Where(p => p)
            .Select(_ => s)
        )
        .Merge()
        .FirstAsync();
    output.WriteLine($"Got result from {server}");
}

private async Task<bool> CallServer(string server, CancellationToken ct)
{
    try
    {
        if (server == "server1")
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), ct);
            output.WriteLine($"{server} finished");
            return false;
        }
        if (server == "server2")
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), ct);
            output.WriteLine($"{server} finished");
            return false;
        }
        if (server == "server3")
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), ct);
            output.WriteLine($"{server} finished");
            return true;
        }
        if (server == "server4")
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4), ct);
            output.WriteLine($"{server} finished");
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch(OperationCanceledException)
    {
        output.WriteLine($"{server} Cancelled");
        throw;
    }

    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(server));
}
```

The test takes 3.32 seconds on my machine (that means it didn't wait for the 4th server) and I got the following output:

```
server1 finished
server2 finished
server3 finished
server4 Cancelled
Got result from server3
```

Comment: I've tried your code sample and it doesn't seem to work quite how I wanted. I can't use `WaitAny` because that just returns when the first  `Task` completes, even if the server wasn't the correct one. I also can't use `WaitAll` otherwise I have to wait for all the tasks to complete even after I've found the correct one. Ideally I want to do "wait until one of the tasks returns true or all tasks complete (i.e. none of the servers was a match)". Is there a way I can accomplish that?

Comment: Updated my answer, but now I would prefer @svick 's answer.

Comment: Marked as answer because I can't use the answer from @svick even though it looks quite nice because I'm on .Net 4.0.

Comment: Updated my answer again, Rx rocks :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`OrderByCompletion()` from the AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TaskExtensions&referringTitle=Documentation), which returns the tasks as they complete. Your code could look something like:

```
var tasks = servers
    .Select(s => Task.Factory.StartNew(server => CallServer((string)server), s))
    .OrderByCompletion();

foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    if (task.Result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("found");
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("not found yet");
}

// cancel any outstanding tasks since the correct server has been found
```

Comment: Doesn't `task.Result` block the current thread until the next task completes? Maybe this should also be done on another thread if the current thread is e.g. the UI thread?

Comment: @Jasd Yes, it does. But the question asks for an improved `WaitAny()`, which also blocks. So I'm assuming that this either isn't a UI application, or it's already running on a separate thread.

Comment: That looks very tidy but unfortunately I'm using VS2010 so I can't use that library.

Comment: @AdamRodger In that case you can use [Jon Skeet's code for that method](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/01/16/eduasync-part-19-ordering-by-completion-ahead-of-time.aspx), or [Stephen Toub's `Interleaved()`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/08/02/processing-tasks-as-they-complete.aspx), which is a bit different (it returns `IEnumerable<Task<Task>>`).

Comment: Jon Skeet's code has moved [here](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/01/16/eduasync-part-19-ordering-by-completion-ahead-of-time/).

Answer (score 1):

Using Interlocked.CompareExchange will do just that, only one Task will be able to write on serverReturedData

```
    public void SearchServers()
        {
            ResultClass serverReturnedData = null;
            var servers = new[] {"server1", "server2", "server3", "server4"};
            var tasks = servers.Select(s => Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(server => 
            {
               var result = CallServer((string)server), s);
               Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref serverReturnedData, result, null);

            }).ToArray();

            Task.WaitAny(tasks); //how do I say "WaitAny where the result is true"?
        //
        // use serverReturnedData as you want.
        // 
        }
```

EDIT: As Jasd said, the above code can return before the variable serverReturnedData have a valid value (if the server returns a null value, this can happen), to assure that you could wrap the result in a custom object.

Comment: After `Task.WaitAny(tasks);` `serverReturnedData` can still change (because of the other Tasks that will finish). Furthermore the first Task that finishs is not guaranteed to be the one that returns `true`.

Comment: The code above guarantees that the first non null value will be stored, on the local variable, if the first task returning returns a null value, yes it will change afterwards. But that can be solved by easily by wrapping the result in a custom object.

Comment: Ok. So first of all, bool is a value type and can't be null, so you may want to change the initial state and the 3rd argument of `Interlocked.CompareExchange` to false. Furthermore, the first task that finishs (the one you wait for in `Task.WaitAny(tasks);`) is not guaranteed to be the one that returns `true`. But IMO the OP wants to wait for the first task that returns `true`.

Comment: True, changed my example, didn't notice the bool declaration xD. Second can be a misunderstanding of mine while reading the question

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic solution based on svick's answer:

```
public static async Task<T> GetFirstResult<T>(
this IEnumerable<Func<CancellationToken, Task<T>>> taskFactories, 
Action<Exception> exceptionHandler,
Predicate<T> predicate)
{
    T ret = default(T);
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var proxified = taskFactories.Select(tf => tf(cts.Token)).ProxifyByCompletion();
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < proxified.Length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            ret = await proxified[i].ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            exceptionHandler(e);
            continue;
        }
        if (predicate(ret))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (i == proxified.Length)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("No task returned the expected value");
    }
    cts.Cancel(); //we have our value, so we can cancel the rest of the tasks
    for (int j = i+1; j < proxified.Length; j++)
    {
        //observe remaining tasks to prevent process crash 
        proxified[j].ContinueWith(
         t => exceptionHandler(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)
                   .Forget();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Where `ProxifyByCompletion` is implemented as:

```
public static Task<T>[] ProxifyByCompletion<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
{
    var inputTasks = tasks.ToArray();
    var buckets = new TaskCompletionSource<T>[inputTasks.Length];
    var results = new Task<T>[inputTasks.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < buckets.Length; i++)
    {
        buckets[i] = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        results[i] = buckets[i].Task;
    }
    int nextTaskIndex = -1;
    foreach (var inputTask in inputTasks)
    {
        inputTask.ContinueWith(completed =>
        {
            var bucket = buckets[Interlocked.Increment(ref nextTaskIndex)];
            if (completed.IsFaulted)
            {
                Trace.Assert(completed.Exception != null);
                bucket.TrySetException(completed.Exception.InnerExceptions);
            }
            else if (completed.IsCanceled)
            {
                bucket.TrySetCanceled();
            }
            else
            {
                bucket.TrySetResult(completed.Result);
            }
        }, CancellationToken.None, 
           TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
    return results;
}
```

And `Forget` is an empty method to suppress CS4014:

```
public static void Forget(this Task task) //suppress CS4014
{
}
```