# How to spawn multiple threads, process the fastest and abort the rest

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Let's say there are multiple ways to do an action and each way is arbitrarily more efficient. I would like to spawn multiple threads to accomplish an action and see which one finishes first. How would I do this? I know that I would spawn multiple threads but the thread that finishes first would have to return a value to the main thread which would have to abort all running threads. This is for learning so I'd like to understand how to do this with threading and with the task library.

Comment: i think `WaitAny()` can do the [trick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdykks7z.aspx) or for TPL you can use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270672.aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726854/task-parallel-library-waitany-with-specified-result - this is pretty much 90% of your question.

Comment: @Vivek Actually that question asks for more than this question. It asks for first result *that matches some condition*, which is more complicated than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make all your alternative ways accept a `CancellationToken`.
2. Create a `CancellationTokenSource` and invoke all the alternative ways as separate `Task`s, passing in the `Token` both to the `Task`s and to the executed methods.
3. Use `Task.WaitAny(tasks)` or `await Task.WhenAny(tasks)` to wait for the fastest `Task` to complete. From the result of that call, you can get the result of the fastest `Task`.
4. `Cancel()` the cancellation token to notify the remaining `Task`s to stop as soon as it's convenient for them.

Comment: @Eitan You mean using the `Thread` class? Why would you want to do that? Most of the time, TPL is much more convenient.

Comment: For my general knowledge but also if I have to use a 2.0 project