# TPL wait for task to complete with a specific return value

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'd like to make a request to X different web services who will each return either `true` or `false`.

These tasks should be executed in parallel and I'd like to wait for the first one that completes **with** a true value. When I receive a true value, I do not wish to wait for the other tasks to complete.

In the example below, `t1` should not be *awaited* since `t3` completes first and returns `true`:

```
var t1 = Task.Run<bool>(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("Task 1 Excecuted");
    return true;
}, cts.Token);

var t2 = Task.Run<bool>(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Task 2 Executed");
    return false;
}, cts.Token);

var t3 = Task.Run<bool>(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine("Task 3 Executed");
    return true;
}, cts.Token);
```

Essentially I'm looking for `Task.WhenAny` with a predicate, which of course doesn't exist.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726854/task-parallel-library-waitany-with-specified-result

Comment: @AdamPlocher that question is less relevant in an `async-await` environment.

Comment: I sense a TPL DataFlow solution in here somewhere, wish I had the time to sit down and play with it!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can simply use `Task.WhenAny` and a predicate multiple times until the "right" task comes along

```
async Task<T> WhenAny<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var taskList = tasks.ToList();
    Task<T> completedTask = null;
    do
    {
        completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(taskList);
        taskList.Remove(completedTask);
    } while (!predicate(await completedTask) && taskList.Any());

    return completedTask == null ? default(T) : await completedTask;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

One option is to use [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx). Lets assume that you have a collection of tasks. It could be the tasks you mentioned in the question:

```
var tasks = new[] { t1, t2, t3 };
```

To execute the tasks in parallel and returning when the first tasks returns `true` you use this expression:

```
var result = await tasks
  .Select(t => t.ToObservable())
  .Merge()
  .FirstOrDefaultAsync(success => success);
```

The tasks are converted into observable sequences that each "fire" once when the task completes. These sequences are then merged into a single sequence which then is "converted" back into something that can be awaited using a predicate. And if necessary you can use a more complicated predicate instead of `success => success`.

After this you can cancel the remaining unfinished tasks if you are using a `CancellationTokenSource`:

```
cts.Cancel();
```

The variable `result` will now be either `true` or `false` and any remaining tasks have been given a signal to cancel.

If you want to test this with your sample tasks you will have to modify them slightly to use `Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep` to enable the task to be cancelled:

```
var t1 = Task.Run<bool>(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cts.Token);
    Console.WriteLine("Task 1 Excecuted");
    return false;
}, cts.Token);
```