# need help in waiting for async webclient post response

Tags: c#, visual-studio, httpwebrequest

Hi i am posting to a url using following method. it works fine for me. i have created five task inside this.

```
private async Task CreateMultipleTasksAsync(string url, ExtendedWebClient oExtendedWebClient, string sParam)
        {

            try
            {
                Task<string> download1 = oExtendedWebClient.ProcessURLAsync(url, oExtendedWebClient, sParam);
                Task<string> download2 = oExtendedWebClient.ProcessURLAsync(url, oExtendedWebClient, sParam);
                Task<string> download3 = oExtendedWebClient.ProcessURLAsync(url, oExtendedWebClient, sParam);
                Task<string> download4 = oExtendedWebClient.ProcessURLAsync(url, oExtendedWebClient, sParam);
                Task<string> download5 = oExtendedWebClient.ProcessURLAsync(url, oExtendedWebClient, sParam);
                lst_tasks1.Add(download1);
                lst_tasks2.Add(download2);
                lst_tasks3.Add(download3);
                lst_tasks4.Add(download4);
                lst_tasks5.Add(download5);

                // Await each task.
                 Result1 = await download1;
                 Result2 = await download2;
                 Result3 = await download3;
                 Result4 = await download4;
                 Result5 = await download5;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLog.createLog("ex.StackTrace = " + ex.StackTrace + " ex.tostring = " + ex.ToString());
            }

        }
```

**what i need to achieve is if any task returns string containing "START" word stop waiting and continue ..**

**The way i am doing this is as follows :**

```
   Task.WaitAll(lst_tasks1.ToArray());
if (Result1.ToLower().Contains("START") && !Result1.Contains(sTextSearch))
{
    goto call2;
}
else
{

worker.ReportProgress(0, "Waiting for tasks2");
Task.WaitAll(lst_tasks2.ToArray());
```

and so on waitng up to task 5. **is there any way to do this code using Task.waitany** please suggest

Comment: Hey there, newbie! Welcome to StackOverflow, also known as SO. This place is very strict and you won't survive in this world if you don't do as we say.We aren't here to write your code. Pose a specific problem such as "Why does this happen?". SO is here so you can ask about a problem, and is not a suitable place for asking us to write code/give you a tutorial.

Comment: i have already posted my code what i have done. just need help in better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You could try using the solution given in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24550932/tpl-wait-for-task-to-complete-with-a-specific-return-value#answer-24551207)

You will need to pass your condition to this method as a predicate.

Assuming lst_tasks contains all the tasks, you could do something like this.

```
await WhenAny(lst_tasks, s => s == "START");
```

This will stop waiting once any task returns START.

Comment: hi ferdin, i dont understand the answer mentioned in given post. i am unable to implement suggested solution in my code. i am new to task. if possible please give me a sample for my solution. i am sorry if i have voilated forum rule.

Comment: I have updated the answer on how you can use the method in your code.
You will need to copy the method for WhenAny from the other post for this to work.

Comment: can  i add one more condition in this parameter like below :  await WhenAny(lst_tasks, s => s == "START" && s != "NEWSTRING");

Comment: Yes. you can add any condition you like. If you have more complex logic, you can even pass a function that computes the logic and returns true or false