# Scatter gather with async await

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a situation where I am interested in the first successful response from an array of services that each support the method

```
Task<Try<SearchResponse>> PerformSearch(SearchRequest request);
```

The `Try` class is a container for a Good/Bad result (like error Monad)

The call to the list of services currently is this

```
var searchResponses = await Task.WhenAll(
        _searchServices.Select(s => s.PerformSearch(request))); 
return searchResponses.FirstOrBad(sr=>sr.IsGood);
```

Where `FirstOrBad` is an extension method that finds the first good result or returns a composite Bad Try with a concatenation of all the errors.

As far as I understand the problem with this is that due to the `WhenAll` the time to find the first good result is limited by the slowest response.

I want to continue execution as soon as I receive the first positive result but not the first (2nd ... etc) result if it is not successful, but also continue execution if all results return unsuccessfully, reporting the lack of success.

I would have thought this is a common problem but have found little when searching for examples. It maybe known by some other term than scatter gather.

Comment: I'd have thought you would be using `Task.WhenAny` or using your `FirstOrBad` implmentation as the aggregator. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Jodrell - aint that `Task.WhenAny` stops when any of the service call is completed? OP need to stop the call _only when_ first good result is found

Comment: Any luck with the `Cancellation Token` of `Task`? Execute the tasks in parallel and when you see a good result, cancel other tasks. _Just some thoughts, have never tried this_

Comment: @Developer, agreed but the OP doesn't want to wait for all to complete either. I'd suggest `FirstOrBad` needs to extend `IEnumerable<Task<Try<SearchResponse>>>` directly and that `PerformSearch` ought to accept a `CancellationToken`.

Comment: This seems to offer what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24550932/tpl-wait-for-task-to-complete-with-a-specific-return-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you

```
public static async Task<Try<T>> FirstOrBad<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<Try<T>>> tasks, Func<Try<T>, bool> predicate)
{
       var taskList = tasks.ToList();
       var completed = new List<Task<Try<T>>>();
       Task<Try<T>> completedTask;
       do
       {
           completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(taskList);
           completed.Add(completedTask);
           taskList.Remove(completedTask);
       } while (!predicate(await completedTask) && taskList.Any());

       return !predicate(await completedTask) ?  new Try<T>(completed.ToString(",")) : await completedTask;
 }
```

Adapter from this answer [TPL wait for task to complete with a specific return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24550932/tpl-wait-for-task-to-complete-with-a-specific-return-value)